# Ошибка несоответствия MIME-типа

Tags: mime-type

Натягиваю сайт на вордпресс. В консоли выводится следующая ошибка:
Ресурс с `http://acme/wp-content/themes/acmejs/parallax-slider/modernizr.custom.28468.js?ver=5.8.1` был заблокирован из-за несоответствия MIME-типа `("text/html") (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`

Однако, в инспекторе показывает следующее:

`script type="text/javascript" src="acme/wp-content/themes/acmejs/parallax-slider/…" id="modernizr-js"></script>`

В чём проблема ?

Comment: Очевидно, в том, что сервер отдаёт неверный MIME-тип для этого файла. А уж почему сервер отдаёт неверный MIME-тип - это уж смотрите сервер, инспектор тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal можете чуть подробнее описать, что нужно делать ? Я абсолютный новичок в этом деле.